# APIM with SignalR WebSocket API share the same endpoint with a HTTP one

Tags: azure, websocket, signalr, azure-api-management

I am trying to integrate the Azure SignalR service with APIM (use it as a reverse proxy). It requires the same subpath (`/client`) to be routed to the SignalR service, but with a different protocol (HTTPs and WebSocket). I am not able to get this done in APIM. When I try to add a WebSocket API it will be added as a separate new API. Any idea how to resolve this or work around it?

I tried this. I added two APIs one for http and one for websocket:

```
HTTP POST: <APIM url>/client/negotiate (no api suffix)
Websocket: <APIM url>/client (suffix: client)
```

After I added above APIs, APIM will always route `client/negotiate` to the websocket one. Looks like a bug for APIM.

```
HTTP POST: <APIM url>/client/negotiate (no api suffix)
Websocket: <APIM url>/client (suffix: client)
```

I would like these two types of request to be routed correctly.

Comment: have you checked the official doc? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/websocket-api?tabs=portal

Comment: Yes, I can import a Websocket API. The problem is the Websocket needs to be added as a new API. It won't work with the HTTP POST one due to a route problem.

Comment: Facing the same problem when using socket.io

Comment: There is a workaround from MS Q&A: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1279656/azure-signalr-service-with-apim. 

You can add a new HTTP Api with suffix /client/negotiate, POST operation with suffix / to handle negotiate requests. 

Websocket: <APIM url>/client (suffix: client)
HTTP POST: <APIM url>/client/negotiate (suffix: client/negotiate)